# How to fix the error "windows sdk is not installed correctly" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

When attempting to click on the "edit WCF configuration option" on my .config file, I am met with a popup error message which says "Windows SDK is not installed correctly".

[image: Attempting to edit WCF config] [image: Error message]

I have tried modifying the individual components as shown to make sure all SDK components are installed but it still has the same error.

[image]

Comment: did you look into install log? Google this "visual studio 2019 installation install log"

Answer (score 0):

You can just choose the menu Tools -> Get Tools and Features
Choose the tab Individual Components and add mising .NET Framework development tools (3.5).

Answer (score -1):

You need to uninstall all Windows SDK's and then reinstall them. Just unmark the options, click modify and mark them again.